# symfony project + wordpress blog in a directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, symfony, vhosts

I would like to build a symfony2 website with the blog manage by wordpress.

```
www.myapp.com        -> managed by symfony2
www.myapp.com/blog/* -> managed by wordpress
```

> **I need symfony2 not to manage with routes www.myapp.com/blog/*. I don't know if I have to modify htaccess, vhosts or symfony config.**

My server config is ubuntu-server 12.04-32 LAMP, with Apache + php 5.4

Comment: you can marry smyfony with wordpress using kayue wordpressBundle

Answer (score 0):

You don't need specify anything in Symfony2 to do not manage www.myapp.com/blog/*. Just create a directory "blog" in web directory and run wordpress as it is :).

Answer (score 0):

you could install it in a separate directory or get it working with Symfony.
I suggest you read up on Symfony Routing:
http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/routing.html

It should be possible, you'd change the routing config the match /blog and have the index action in the blog controller in symfony to point / work with the Wordpress install.